# How to set Action Bar width in Android application?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application I use Action Bar and navigation mode, that uses tabs. But on a tablet action bar has a very small width. What should I do? Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: actionbar looks to have the proper width to me

Comment: @tyczj Do you mean, that tabs by themselves are to narrow?

Comment: the tabs are not the action bar

Comment: @tyczj Yeah, I know. So what should I do?

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying then, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @tyczj I want my tabs to occupy the whole screen in horizontal direction and I want them to have equal width

Comment: then you cant use actionbar tabs because they dont do that. you need to use the regular `TabHost`